# extracting text from a json string in R with double quotes

Tags: r, regex, string-matching, stringr

I am trying to extract the content in the body string of the JSON object. The problem is I am unable to pass the double quotes to and to extract all the text information. In this case, I need the text as "There is a typo error in documentation regarding a link to a librarys function, which is quite irritating while browsing the documentation!". I have put my code here and if some one can suggest how to pass double quotes instead of (",) and can reach to this greedy quantifier, (here is the expression which I have been using),

```
body<- str_extract(json_file , 'body[^,]*\\s*').
```

Thanks

```
library(stringr)
json_file<- '{ "_id" : ObjectId( "539163d7bd350003" ), "login" :    "vui", "id" : 369607, "avatar_url" : "https://avatars.mashupsusercontent.com/u/369607?", "gravatar_id" : "df8897ffebe16c5b0cd690925c63e190", "body":"There is a typo error in documentation regarding a link to a librarys function, which is quite irritating while browsing the documentation!","url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui", "html_url" : "https://mashups.com/vui", "followers_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/followers", "following_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/following{/other_user}", "gists_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/gists{/gist_id}", "starred_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/starred{/owner}{/repo}", "subscriptions_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/subscriptions", "organizations_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/orgs", "repos_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/repos", "events_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/events{/privacy}", "received_events_url" : "https://api.mashups.com/users/vui/received_events", "type" : "User", "site_admin" : false, "org" : "amurath"}'
body<- str_extract(json_file , 'body[^,]*\\s*')

body
```

Comment: The given string is not a valid JSON object. So you have a string that is still somehow JSONish. Unless you can't define, what JSONish means, any quote pattern might be valid in your eyes.

Comment: I put a validated JSON object, let me know if you have any thoughts! Thank you, Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me..

```
  library(stringr)
  body <- str_extract(json_file, 'body":"[^"]*')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input has a single, ill-formed example, so I have little confidence that this will work on the rest of your data. However,  a way to get what you want on *this data* is:

```
gsub('.*?body.*?:\"(.*?)\",\"\\w+\"\\s*:.*', "\\1", json_file)
```

> [1] "For the spout users such as myself, /reload is not an option
>   because it crashes the spout framework. Also, reloads take a while. I
>   was wondering if you could implement a command to reload the
>   \"configurations\".\r\nThat is all, have a Happy New
>   Year!\r\n-asleeponduty"

**Edit:** I made a minor modification. The new version works on both your old example and the new one.

```
gsub('.*?body.*?:\"(.*?)\",\"\\w+\"\\s*:.*', "\\1", json_file)
```

> [1] "There is a typo error in documentation regarding a link to a
>   librarys function, which is quite irritating while browsing the
>   documentation!"

Comment: I have made some edits for a valid JSON please suggest your thoughts